# Measuring the number of times a line of code gets executed in Eclipse without suspending thread

Tags: eclipse

I am having some trouble with Eclipse debugger and I cannot find the solution here. Basically, I want to measure how many times a particular line of code gets hit without stopping the thread. Breakpoints suspend the thread and I want something similar to breakpoints except that the program keeps running and a counter counts how many times, for instance, a method gets executed.

Comment: the easiest way would be to use a static var and print it: `class X { volatile static int a = 0; void methodToTest() {System.out.println(++a);}` Is this enough?

Comment: Conditional breakpoints are the way to go in Eclipse. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252597/debugging-and-counting-breakpoint-hits