# Counting breakpoint hits

Tags: eclipse, debugging

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252597/debugging-and-counting-breakpoint-hits) is over 3 years old, I figured I'd bring it up again.  Especially since the solution offered there isn't a real option for me.

I'm looking for a way to count passes over a particular breakpoint in the eclipse debugger without actually suspending the code.  I need to do this because the issue I'm working on manifests itself only when thousands of messages are sent per second.

The solution offered above is not really feasible for me, as the code being debugged is in a remote location and I cannot really create the static class to track hits.  Is there either a default feature or a plugin that will simply count breakpoint hits, or is it not possible in eclipse?

Comment: Is the "Hit count" option in the breakpoint properties not appropriate? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The Hit count option causes eclipse to break when the breakpoint has been passed that number of times, and ignore the breakpoint other times.  it doesnt actually track the number of hits

Comment: I see, then I was missing something. :) I don't think it is possible to do it in vanilla Eclipse then. You can probably build your own plugin to do it.

Comment: A left-field idea is to use [spf4j](http://zolyfarkas.github.io/spf4j/) to track your application, but that isn't exactly real time.

Comment: When do break or when do you want to get the hit count value?

Comment: In any way, it will have a performance impact. It sounds like an XY problem to me. What do you really want to achieve where you think counting breakpoints would help?

Comment: @Thomas I never want to break. The goal is that I am sending thousands of messages per second and I want to track as whether the correct.code path is being covered for every message. If not, I want to see what percentage of the time something goes wrong. This is just an initial debugging step

Comment: If you don't want to break, when and where do you want to get the hit count number? After the debugging session is over, the number is gone if you don't log it into a file or something. BTW: why not implement a unit test to check if messages are going the correct path?

Answer (score 3):

Actually in said question the only reason to use another class is to have a dedicated static variable that you can access from the breakpoint snippet. You can use any other static variable/method that is visble to the snippet.

For instance:

```
int a = System.getProperty("my-prop");
System.setProperty("my-prop", ++a);
```

That might be slow, so you could try with `ThreadLocal`s or find youself a static var (or preferably a map to track many places) that you can hijack for this purpose.